# Moved server, now photos don't display

Tags: channel-images

I've run out of ideas on how to fix this one. I moved a site to another server, and now the photos don't display. I've moved sites before without a problem. I did the following:

1. Confirmed the paths were correct.
2. Checked all folder (777) and file permissions (666).
3. Ran file synchronization.
4. Cleared all caches.
5. Optimized the database.
6. Re-saved some test photos.

New photos display correctly. When I use my browser to go to the exact path of an old photo, it won't display, even though the path and file permissions are correct.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that multiple problems were involved. The list of steps in my original post cleared up some of them, while others were simply the result of people renaming, deleting or overwriting photos on the new site. I guess the devil is in the details.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a plugin such as CE_Image then ensure your image directories are writeable.

If they are, and your server isn't running out of memory (unlikely as it would just fall over if that was the case) then I'd put money on your paths being incorrect (even though you say they're correct) :)

I don't know if there is some database setting with Channel Images that needs to be updated.

Comment: If I download the photo and upload it again, it appears. In either case, the path is the same: img src="{filedir_6}Delgaudio_Pic.jpg". Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

If using CE Image, it is possible that the relative URL paths don't match the server directory structure. [More info](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/common-solutions)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not using CE image or any other image plugins.

Answer (score 0):

That the new photos display correctly but the old ones don't point to the file upload paths have been updated but not synchronized. But you stated that you did synchronize. So perhaps the paths are hard coded in the templates, or even a portion of the path.

I would inspect the source code of the generated page, check the path to the image and see what errors occur.

Comment: I had the same thought, but no luck. As I mentioned above, the paths use a standard approach: img src="{filedir_6}Delgaudio_pic.jpg" with the file directory ID correct. It's almost as if the database itself rather than the software is the problem.